# JavaScript play() function does not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I created an audio object and want to play it when user leave the window. So, my code is here:

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', function(){
    var audio = new Audio( 'quite-impressed.mp3' )
    audio.play()
})
```

It works well in Firefox. It also works in Chrome if I click in the page and then leave mouse outside of the body. But, when I leave the mouse without clicking in the page an error showed in the console and the audio does not play

**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes**

But, in this [example site](https://www.2weekdiet.com/) it works fine without interacting with the page. How can I make it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is in the link you've added right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they use an AudioContext to play that sound.
Chrome did came back a few months ago about blocking the AudioContext API, because a lot of fair uses were not prepared for such restriction and thus got broken by it.

But M71, which will get released in December 2018 will reenable that restriction, you can read about it here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio

```
// this will work in Chrome < 70 but not af
onmouseout = e => {
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const osc = ctx.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(ctx.destination);
  osc.start(0);
  osc.stop(1);
}
```

Outsourced live example, since Stacksnippets are always granted the user gesture anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/zy3ev8ka/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Chrome 77:

- On address bar: chrome://settings/content/sound
- Turn off "Allow sites to play sound (recommended)"
- Turn it on again

Comment: As a developer, I want to make it work for end users and with default browser settings. You know it's working by by changing browser settings, but not everyone knows that - who visited my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`window.audio = new Audio( 'quite-impressed.mp3' )
$('body').on('mouseleave', function(){
    audio.play()
})`

Comment: No, it does't work yet. It's a browser specific problem. Chrome want to prevent to play an audio without interacting to that window.

Answer (score 0):

if your js play function is not running and if your code is correct then this may help,you have to allow your browser to get that sound file

just goto settings =>privacy and security => site-settings =>sound.
and then add your local url at add to play section..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31729976)